# Scala Regular Expressions (string delimited by double quotes)

Tags: regex, scala, double-quotes

I am new to scala.  I am trying to match a string delimited by double quotes, and I am a bit puzzled by the following behavior:

If I do the following:

```
val stringRegex = """"([^"]*)"(.*$)"""
val regex = stringRegex.r
val tidyTokens = Array[String]("1", "\"test\"", "'c'", "-23.3")
tidyTokens.foreach {
    token => if (token.matches (stringRegex)) println (token + " matches!")
}
```

I get

```
"test" matches!
```

otherwise, if I do the following:

```
tidyTokens.foreach {
    token => token match {
        case regex(token) => println (token + " matches!")
        case _ => println ("No match for token " + token)
    }
}
```

I get

```
No match for token 1
No match for token "test"
No match for token 'c'
No match for token -23.3
```

Why doesn't "test" match in the second case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take your regular expression:

```
 "([^"]*)"(.*$)
```

When compiled with `.r`, this string yields a `regex` object - which, if it matches it's input string, must yield **2** captured strings - one for the `([^"]*)` and the other for the `(.*$)`. Your code

```
  case regex(token) => ...
```

Ought to reflect this, so maybe you want

```
  case regex(token, otherStuff) => ...
```

Or just

```
  case regex(token, _) => ...
```

Why? Because the `case regex(matchedCaputures...)` syntax works because `regex` is an 
object with an `unapplySeq` method.  `case regex(token) => ...` translates (roughly) to:

```
 case List(token) => ...
```

Where `List(token)` is what `regex.unapplySeq( inputString )` returns:

```
 regex.unapplySeq("\"test\"") // Returns Some(List("test", ""))
```

Your regex does match the string `"test"` but in the `case` statement the regex extractor's `unapplySeq` method returns a list of **2** strings because that is what the regex says it captures.  That's unfortunate, but the compiler can't help you here because regular expressions are compiled from strings at runtime.

One alternative would be to use a non-capturing group:

```
 val stringRegex = """"([^"]*)"(?:.*$)"""
 //                             ^^
```

Then your code would work, because `regex` will now be an extractor object whose
`unapplySeq` method returns only a single captured group:

```
 tidyTokens foreach { 
    case regex(token) => println (token + " matches!")
    case t => println ("No match for token " + t)
 }
```

Have a look at the tutorial on [Extractor Objects](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112), for a better understanding on 
how `apply` / `unapply`  / `unapplySeq` works.

Comment: Thanks! Also for the reference to the Extractor Objects!