# Scala match case on regex directly

Tags: scala

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
list.foreach {x => 
     x match {
       case """TEST: .*""" => println( "TEST" )
       case """OXF.*"""   => println("XXX")
       case _             => println("NO MATCHING")
     }
}
```

The idea is to use it like groovy switch case regex match. But I can't seem to get to to compile. Whats the right way to do it in scala?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could either match on a precompiled regular expression (as in the first case below), or add an `if`
clause. Note that you typically don't want to recompile the same regular expression on each `case` evaluation, but rather have it on an object.

```
val list = List("Not a match", "TEST: yes", "OXFORD")
   val testRegex = """TEST: .*""".r
   list.foreach { x =>
     x match {
       case testRegex() => println( "TEST" )
       case s if s.matches("""OXF.*""") => println("XXX")
       case _ => println("NO MATCHING")
     }
   }
```

See more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119238/scala-regular-expressions-string-delimited-by-double-quotes) and some background [here](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Regular-expression-matching-td1991061.html).

Comment: I wish scala added more syntactic sugar for handling this, I don't like the extra codes for matching simpler regex. After spending quite some time to find out how to do it, I couldn't believe its not doable in Scala hence the StackOverflow post!

Comment: use `val testRegex = """TEST: (.*)""".r` and `case testRegex(m) => println("TEST "+m)` to capture the match

Answer (score 12):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, it's possible to directly pattern match a `String` by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
// val examples = List("Not a match", "TEST: yes", "OXFORD")
examples.map {
  case s"TEST: $x" => x
  case s"OXF$x"    => x
  case _           => ""
}
// List[String] = List("", "yes", "ORD")
```