# can I combine multiple string matching cases in scala?

Tags: scala

Can I combine the following two cases into one `case` clause since they both do the same thing?

```
e match {
  case "hello" => e + "world"
  case "hi" => e + "world
}
```

Also, what about if I want to match using `startsWith` e.g.,

```
e match { case e.startsWith("he") | e.startsWith("hi") => ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can simply use `or (|)` to `match` one of the `pattern`,

```
scala> "hi" match { case "hello" | "hi" => println("fantastic")  case _ => println("very very bad")}
fantastic

scala> "hello" match { case "hello" | "hi" => println("fantastic")  case _ => println("very very bad")}
fantastic

scala> "something else" match { case "hello" | "hi" => println("fantastic")  case _ => println("very very bad")}
very very bad
```

You can also use **regex** to pattern match, especially useful when there are many criterias to match,

```
scala> val startsWithHiOrHello = """hello.*|hi.*""".r
startsWithHiOrHello: scala.util.matching.Regex = hello.*|hi.*

scala> "hi there" match { case startsWithHiOrHello() => println("fantastic")  case _ => println("very very bad")}
fantastic

scala> "hello there" match { case startsWithHiOrHello() => println("fantastic")  case _ => println("very very bad")}
fantastic

scala> "non of hi or hello there" match { case startsWithHiOrHello() => println("fantastic")  case _ => println("very very bad")}
very very bad
```

Refer to [Scala multiple type pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15656032/432903) and [Scala match case on regex directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15696785/432903)

Comment: @JRR in that case regex is better idea instead of `OR`. see the updated example.  you would basically need `hi.*|hello.*` regex